# How to get rid of global variables in my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables, refactoring

I was sitting all week on this and I don't know how to get rid of these `global points`.

Here I define `points`.

```
def init():
   global points, hidden_password, hidden_password2, country, used, start_time
   points = 0
   hidden_password = []
   hidden_password2 = []
   country = ""
   used = []
   start_time = datetime.now()
   welcome()
   choice()
```

Then it goes to `choice()` from choice to `play_game()` than to `guessing_capital()` and here I use points for the first time, and the program is working until var `points` reach 5.

```
def guessing_capital(password, used, user_name):
    global points
    while points < 5:
        checking(password, user_name)
        time.sleep(1)
        print("\n Letters You failed guessing: ", ", ".join(used), end=".\n")

    time.sleep(2)
    print("\n *** You lost! Sorry, but the GAME is OVER! ***\n")
    time.sleep(3)
    init()
```

Then it goes to `checking()` and from checking it goes to the `letter()` and then to `checking_password()` where if the user didn't guess right letter it adds 1 to `points` and returns it.

```
def checking_password(number):
    global points, hidden_password2, hidden_password
    if hidden_password2 == hidden_password:
        points += number
    time.sleep(1)
    print("\n Boo! You have +", number, "penalty points!")
    time.sleep(1)
    hidden_password2 = hidden_password
    if points < 4:
        manage_graphics(points)
    elif points == 4:
        manage_graphics(points)
        print(" Hint: It's a capital of " + country + ".")
    elif points >= 5:
        manage_graphics(5)
    return points
```

Here is a full code if someone wants: https://codeshare.io/aYBAzb

Comment: can't follow the link, it is broken for me

Comment: Pass them as an argument.

Comment: I tried but I was getting 0 as points all the time

Comment: other link: https://github.com/Kaspazza/Python/blob/master/Hangman/Hangman.py

Comment: Define a `class` and make them instance attributes. You can do it anytime, but commonly this is done in the `__init__()` method.

Comment: @ScottHunter: That approach won't always work if any of the variables need to be modified (depending on why type they are).

Comment: I got stuck I added __init__(self, points=0), and changed points everywhere for self.points but now init() is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a class to store attributes.

```
Class Game:
    def __init__():
        points = 0
        self.hidden_password = []
        self.hidden_password2 = []
        self.country = ""
        self.used = []
        self.start_time = datetime.now()
        self.welcome()  # This should be in main function
        self.choice()  # This should be in main function
    def choice(self, ...):
        pass        
    def welcome(self, ...):
        pass
    def guessing_capital(self, ...):
        pass
    def checking_password(self, ...):
        pass
```